# OpenGL Shader variable passing

Tags: c, opengl, shader

I read many articles and posts about passing values like vectors and matrices from the vertex shader stage to the fragment shader. But I'm still not sure about this:
If you have some out vars in the vertex shader (I'll call him vtxs) and some in vars in the fragment shader (frgs), how does OpenGl associate them so they refer to the same value (i neglect the fact that values passing to frgs are interpolated)? Must I write them down in the some order? And how does OpenGl interpret these variables if I write:

**vtxs:**

```
out float x;
out vec4 mvp;
```

**frgs:**

```
in vec4 mvp;
in float x;
in double newvar;
```

**Note:** I shuffled the var types and there is 1 more in var in frgs then out vars in vtxs.

I see that location spec in the layout list is a way to assign a ... address? ... to a variable but I have an ancient netbook doesnt supporting such a variable decorator.

and as a tip: do you know some sort of debugging shaders? i mean, in cpu programs you can add some printfs but i didnt see such a func in glsl...

So, summarized, that are my questions:

1. What the heck do you specify with the layout(location=...) what consequences are there concerning the shader?
2. How does the value matching/association between various shader stages work? With and without that "location="?
3. debugging glsl shaders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the inputs and outputs are matched by name between interfaces. For the vertex shader inputs, the default 'automatic' assignment of indexes is [arbitrary](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Inputs), in the sense that it may differ between implementations.

The `layout` qualifier allow to explicitly specify both the storage type and location of a input\output. Because of the automatic assignment of vertex inputs is arbitrary, you should use the `layout` location in GLSL or the function `glBindAttribLocation​` to guarantee that apples are apples and oranges oranges.

So the `layout` specification is very common in vertex shaders. But it can be used between any interface. For instance, if you didn't used the same name for the `vec4` and `float`, you would have done

**vtxs:**

```
layout(location = 0) out float x;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 mvp;
```

**frgs:**

```
layout(location = 0) in float y;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 pvm;
```

Now any input which is not present in the interface will break the pipeline. if you use a new variable

```
in double newvar;
```

then `glLinkProgram` will fail.

**Debugging:**
The first debugging step is to check the status shader compilation and linking. On failure you can retrieve the error using `glGetShaderInfoLog`.

```
//compilation
glCompileShader(shader);
glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if(!success)
{
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
}

//program
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
GLint success;
glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
if(!success)
{
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
}
```

You can also

- [write your tests right into the shader](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-can-i-debug-glsl-shaders)
- [use external tool which intercept opengl function calls](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34392/debugging-shader-code)

Comment: so it is enough that variable names matches (if i have no supported layout(location)). in this case, your example wont link, because you have 'mvp' and 'mpv'. is that correct?

Comment: yes it is enough. But my example will link, because by stating an explicit location of input and outputs the linker will not consider variable names. He will still perform type checking.

Comment: Note that using `location` matching between shader stages requires OpenGL version 4.2 or ARB_separate_shader_objects

Comment: @NicolBolas As far as I can tell, the `location` qualifiers for all shader stages were introduced in GLSL 4.10: "All shaders allow input layout qualifiers on input variable declarations."

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Eh, one decimal place is close enough, right ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas If you did it from memory, it's actually pretty good. ;) I looked it up because I had never even seen this usage of `location` before.

Answer (score 1):

By default the variables between stages get matched by name.

For the location, you can conceptually look at the data passed between stages as an array of vec4's. Then location is the index of the array which we use to pass that variable.

Types larger than a vec4 get multiple consecutive locations. For newer opengl versions (or ARB_enhanced_layouts) these is also a component layout-qualifier to pack values more closely in that vec4 array.

I am not sure how locations get assigned when matching by name and location is mixed.

Comment: >>> For the location, you can conceptually look at the data passed between stages as an array of vec4's.

Comment: so, any var is stored into a vec4? also floats and ints?

Comment: conceptually, yes (although note that for types other than float, they are not converted to a float, so they keep their exact value). In practice the driver can pack them together during linking. This matters most when using seperate shaders as then there is no linking between the different stages.